# Find a real number with even digits in a given base

Tags: algorithms, number-theory

A real number `x ∈ (0,1)` is called **b-good** if `x` converted to any base `b >= 2` has **all digits even**.

On input I have `b, p, q` where `p, q` are positive integers, `p <= q`. How can I check if `x = p / q` is a b-good number?

Comment: Do the long division until it repeats?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't understand what do you mean by long division... can you tell me more details?

Comment: "Long division" is the usual pencil-and-paper method for dividing numbers by each other, usually taught in elementary school. Divide $p$ by $q$, working in base $b$, until the remainders start repeating. Check whether all of the digits of the quotient you've produced are even.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but I think this is not the optimal way to solve the problem. I need an algorithm optimal to solve this, and I can't figure out how to implement an optimal solution for this problem. Thanks anyway for explanation :)

Comment: x @kitz, if you have a more efficient method in mind, feel free to write an answer to the question yourself.

Comment: At this moment I don't have any better idea :(.